# Cucumber focus md-list-item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cucumber, angular-material

I'm creating a website with Angular Material, and using Cucumber script for testing. Is it possible for Cucumber to focus on ?

I tried to give  an id, but it seems Cucumber can't find the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find we can dynamically add class name to the automatically generated html tag.

For example, you created  list like below:

```
<md-list flex>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line tobe-reviewed-kudo-item" ng-repeat="kudo in kudos | filter : {kudosStatus: 'Pending'} | limitTo : 3" ng-click="toReviewKudo(kudo.kudosId)">
        <img ng-src="img/avatar.png" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.who}}" />
        <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
            <h3>{{kudo.chEmployeeByKudosSenderId}} sent {{kudo.chEmployeeByKudosReceiverId}}</h3>
            <p>{{kudo.createdOn}}</p>
        </div>
        <p>{{kudo.kudosStatus}}</p>
        <md-divider></md-divider>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

If you use cucumber script to focus md-list-item, it won't work because Angular Material will generate the clickable button dynamically. We need to give those buttons class name to let cucumber script focus on them. Hence, after we bind the data, we can use blow code to give class name:

```
$scope.$watch("$viewContentLoaded", function() {
 var kudoItemsDOM = document.getElementsByClassName("tobe-reviewed-kudo-item");
 var kudoItems = angular.element(kudoItemsDOM);
 for(var i = 0; i < kudoItems.length; i++) {
 angular.element(kudoItems[i].querySelector(".md-ink-ripple")).addClass("kudo-item-btn");
 }
 });
```

Then, kudo-item-btn will be added to the html, and cucumber can focus these buttons.